# Robolectric AsyncTask callback

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-asynctask, robolectric, powermockito

I want to test method that are executed in AsyncTask. I already mocked all methods inside. What I have -

1. Static method that get all required parameters and do new AsyncTask().executeOnExecutor();
2. In onPostExecute() I call callback with result.

For test I'm using:

```
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.2.2"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.4"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.4"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.4"
testCompile "org.powermock:powermock-classloading-xstream:1.6.4"
```

But callback is never called. Example :

```
  @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 24,
            application = StubApplicationClass.class)
    @PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.", "android.*"})
    @PrepareForTest(BaseHttpClient.class)

    @SuppressStaticInitializationFor("io.realm.internal.Util")
    public class GetDataTest {

        @Rule
        public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();
        ....................................

        @Test
        public void getDataTest() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("started");
        BaseAsyncClient.doAsync(UserPublicDataTable, Actions,
                list, new IHttpResponse<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void httpResponse(@Nullable String response) {
                        assertNotNull(response); System.out.println("onPostExecute()");
                    }
                });
        System.out.println("finished");
    }
```

onPostExecute - is never printed.

When I call:

```
Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
```

I receive an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.getBackgroundThreadScheduler(Robolectric.java:193)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler(Robolectric.java:200)
```

**How can I test AsyncTask with robolectric, powermock ?**

**Update**:

As I see `ShadowApplication.getInstance() ==  null`, that is why I receive NPE exception when calls '`flushBackgroundThreadScheduler`'.

I created [custom runner to create custom application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725309/robolectric-not-using-test-application), but it is still null.

To fix NPE in Application migrated to:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"
```

UPDATE:

When I create AsyncTask in @Test  - it works

```
new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            System.out.println("empty async task");
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
    ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();
    Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler();
```

So problem when task is created with 'static' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem with a little work-around:

1. downgrade version to *testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"*
2. Call async tas  *new AsyncTask.execute()*
3. Call *ShadowApplication.executeBackgroundTasks();*
4. Sleep while background executed *Thread.sleep(1000);*
5. Execute foregroud tasks with *ShadowScheduler*

Unfortunately, this require to wait till background thread executed. I didn't found a way to replace background thread with main as well.

In the end, I migrated from AsyncTask to RxJava. 
There, with default methods I replace thread pool executor with the same thread execution:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
 RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(new Function<Scheduler, Scheduler>() {
            @Override
            public Scheduler apply(Scheduler scheduler) throws Exception {
                return ImmediateThinScheduler.INSTANCE;
            }
        });
```

`Schedulers.io()` is the thread pool executor, I replace it with the same thread executor `ImmediateThinScheduler.INSTANCE`